# Unable to pass MemoryStream parameter to WCF method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, silverlight

I have a method in Service1.svc.cs, below is the code

```
public void SaveData(int UserId, System.IO.MemoryStream File)
{
   //Some code
}
```

I am passing values from xaml.cs

```
savedata.SaveDataAsync(userId, ms);
```

The error is

> cannot convert from 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to
>   'SignSilverlight.ServiceReference1.MemoryStream'

How to solve ?

Comment: change `System.IO` to `SignSilverlight.ServiceReference1`

Comment: unable to add the SignSilverlight.ServiceReference namespace to the file,the error is at 'savedata.SaveDataAsync(userId , ms);' ms is in red lines and it wants ms as SignSilverlight.ServiceReference.MemoryStream

Comment: can you provide a bit more code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory stream is a .NET local object and it is not possible to pass it to a remote machine that might not even run .NET.

You have to pass a byte[] array instead. But be aware of size limits in endpoint's settings.

Here is how to (de)serialize a memory stream to array

```
 // first endpoint
 var streamSending = new MemoryStream();
 var array = streamSending.ToArray();

 // second endpoint
 var streamRecieving = new MemoryStream(array);
```